# SQL Server: how to test a trigger that doesn't throw errors but only prints statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

My trigger checks if a condition is true, and if so throws a warning with a `PRINT` statement. This later gets caught by the JDBC, for use in the front-end.

My question: how can I make a test for the trigger in T-SQL? I have a testing USP that checks if ERROR_NUMBER equals the specified trigger error, but that only works if the trigger actually throws said error message, which this trigger isn't supposed to do.

Is there an alternative to using a PRINT perhaps, that I can catch in my testing USP, without interrupting the statement? (it is supposed to function anyway)

To make it more concrete: my database is about fishes and aquaria. When you put a carnivorous fish and a herbivorous fish in the same tank, it should give a warning (which my front-end will catch), but not restrict the action. How do I check if that warning was given using a testing USP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [RAISEERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql).

From the article:

> RAISERROR can be used as an alternative to PRINT to return messages to calling applications. RAISERROR supports character substitution similar to the functionality of the printf function in the C standard library, while the Transact-SQL PRINT statement does not. The PRINT statement is not affected by TRY blocks, while a RAISERROR run with a severity of 11 to 19 in a TRY block transfers control to the associated CATCH block. Specify a severity of 10 or lower to use RAISERROR to return a message from a TRY block without invoking the CATCH block.

So you can use raiserror with a severity of 10 or lower if you don't want to go into the catch block or 11 to 19 if you want to take action (such as removing the inserted data) in the catch block.

Edit:

Since you can't use both msg_id and msg_str you would need to use sp_addmessage to add the error to the sys.messages catalog first then use msg_id instead of msg_string.

From the linked article:

> msg_id Is a user-defined error message number stored in the sys.messages catalog view using sp_addmessage. Error numbers for user-defined error messages should be greater than 50000. When msg_id is not specified, RAISERROR raises an error message with an error number of 50000.

Comment: I have tried working with that... it seems I cannot specify both a number and a message using that function?

Comment: Ehm, did you just edit my question rather than your answer? ^^;

Comment: Yes it seems I clicked the wrong box.  Sorry about that.  Edited my answer now.

Comment: Now it seems to be impossible for me to find warnings with T-SQL :( It's not in the error log...

Comment: Are you using WITH LOG on RAISERROR?